# Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter

I have this error : Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' on this line of code :

```
        double d=double.parse(map2["gain_gem"]);
```

map2["gain_gem"] is returned by php script api and return value 1

And after i try to do this :

```
globals.points = globals.points+d;
```

i have tried too :

```
globals.points = globals.points+double.parse(map2["gain_gem"]);
```

same problem

globals.points is defined as double in my script

```
double points=0;
```

Comment: Provide json object you getting from api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the int as a String first. The map2 value "gain_gem" is an int, that's where your error is coming from but to parse that value as a double it needs to be a String so if you toString the input it will be able to change it to a double. You should definitely make sure it will always be an int of course.

```
double d=double.parse(map2["gain_gem"].toString());
```

[Documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/double/toString.html) on toString()

Comment: Thank you :) So double.parse need to have string parameters it was my problem the value was int, so now i know it. Very Thanks